# Focus issue with Custom Task Pane and WebBrowser Control in Outlook 2010/2016

Tags: vsto, webbrowser-control, outlook-addin

I have Outlook Plugin (using VSTO .net) which opens HTML5 form in the custom task pane of outlook.

Issue: Ctrl + A, TAB events are not working with HTML native controls like Text area after clicking on any outlook fields.
For example I open meeting/email window with my form and then try to write anything in the text area and then press Ctrl + A it works fine. But now If i click on any outlook native fields and then go back to html form text area I cannot do Ctrl + A as well as TAB key is also not working. However, I am able to write any text in that text area.

This issue has been reported to below msdn forum as well and workaround has been provide however, that can have potential issues with some controls like dropdown.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e411bc7-1dba-4a22-86a6-20529e4fe8ea/focus-problems-with-task-pane-and-webcontrol-in-outlook?forum=outlookdev

For ease adding workaround to fix this issue here:

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
        HtmlDocument doc;
        doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.Click += doc_Click;
  }

void doc_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
  {
        this.Focus();  // force user control to have the focus
        HtmlElement elem = 
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
        elem.Focus(); // then let the clicked control to have focus
  }
```

I though this issue will be only limited to outlook 2010 but it's still there with outlook 2016.

**Please note I have verified this behaviour with WinForm and WebBrowser control and it works fine there. Only issue is with Outlook.**

Do anyone else has faced this issue before and is there any proper fix ?

Please refer link provided above which has youtube link to understand issue exactly.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Any news on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting a web browser inside any Office application is really a bad idea. Even various issues remain in all Office and .NET Framework versions caused by a partial incompatibility of the WPF core and Office GUI.

As a workaround you may consider re-creating the GUI using Windows forms controls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. recreating the GUI is not an option actually. We have been using outlook with flex form since years now without any major issues but not we are considering it to recreate using html..